# Can this shape be solved for lengths AB and AC.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

The picture below shows a square with sides of length 10, and line $DO$ with length 4. $O$ is the center of the square. Solve for lengths $AB$ and $AC$?

[image]

My basic maths is failing me here, is this solvable? I think it is because the length of the hypotenuse $BC$ will be determined by how far it is away from the origin $O$. I've tried every basic highschool calculation I know of and have only figured out that I'm stupid. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Fun fact - This is not linear algebra!

Comment: Ah sorry, I am doing this in the context computer graphic programming so I tagged it anyway. I'll remove the tag as I guess it has been abstracted away from linear algebra.

Comment: Chill man i was sarcastically saying that ;)

Comment: I'm chilled as ice. You're correct though.

Comment: What have you tried? How far did you get? Several approaches are possible and you should reach a solution if you stick at it.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

**Hint:**

Consider the lower semi-circular arc
of the circle with radius $r=4$ centered at $O$.
Its equation is
\begin{align}
y(x)&=-\sqrt{16-x^2}
,\\
y'(x)
&=
\frac x{\sqrt{16-x^2}}
.
\end{align}

The point $D$ is a tangent point of the line $BC$,

\begin{align}
y'(x)&=\tan(180^\circ-50^\circ)
=-\tan 50^\circ
\end{align}

\begin{align}
D_x &= 
-4\sin 50^\circ
\approx -3.064
,\\
D_y&=-4\cos 50^\circ
\approx -2.571
.
\end{align}

Given the locatio of the point $D$, we can find that

\begin{align}
|AB|&=
5-\frac{4-5\sin 50^\circ}{\cos 50^\circ}
\approx 4.73587
,\\
|AC|&=
5-\frac{4-5\cos 50^\circ}{\sin 50^\circ}
\approx 3.97387
,\\
|BC|&=
\frac{5\,(\cos 50^\circ+\sin 50^\circ)-4}{\cos 50^\circ\,\sin50^\circ}
\approx 6.182242
\end{align}

Diagram for pure trigonometry:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let $AB=b$ and $AC=c$. With $A$ as origin the equation of line $BC$ is $$y=b-\frac{b}{c} x$$ $$cy+bx-cb=0$$

The co-ordinates of $O$ are $(5, 5)$. The perpendicular distance of the point $O$ from line $BC$ is therefore $$4=\frac{|5c+5b-cb|}{\sqrt{c^2+b^2}}=5(\cos50^{\circ}+\sin50^{\circ})-b\cos50^{\circ}$$ from which $b$ can be found. Then $$c=b\frac{\cos50^{\circ}}{\sin50^{\circ}}$$